# .NET Core BitBucket Pipeline Builds Fail - Wants project.json when I have .csproj

Tags: asp.net-core, bitbucket, project.json, bitbucket-pipelines, schema.yml

I was searching before posting but it seems that VS2017 stops using project.json and instead uses .csproj file so when I try to run builds on either TFS or BitBucket, I get fails because the builds are looking for a project.json. Specifically a BitBucket pipeline will tell me that it can't find the project.json in a .Net Core project. Before I could simply run builds without a problem.

I am new to all of this so is this something I have to change or set in the .yml? Or is this something that BitBucket would have to change in their .Net Core pipelines?

Thanks for any assistance on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so after discussing for a while with bitbucket employees, this image works.

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk
```

BUT that's not all. In the .csproj file there are two  sections IF you have your own project files added to the wwwroot, like .css and .js etc files referenced by . The builds were throwing an error on this. I had to comment out that entire  to get builds to pass on bitbucket pipelines. I have not seen any downside to doing this as my project still runs as normal and still uses my files. If I run into an issue I will come back and update this answer. But for now this is the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Try image: microsoft/dotnet:latest and see if that helps.